# Should my API accept to create resource from clients?

Tags: database, rest, database-design

I'm building an API which use my clients' products so that a client has to push a product to the API to access its services. In your opinion, is it a good/bad practice to accept an id from the client, to concatenate it with the client's id and use it as the product id ? Why?

The point is to relief the client from handle his product ID vs API GUID matching.

EDIT: As an example, please consider the following call : You are pushing one of your product to benefit from the service my api can offer. Should I let you pass your own product id and use it in the database as my product primary key. Or should I generate an UUID/GUID and returns it to you so that you will use it for future reference ?

POST : https://awesome-api/my-products

```
{
    id: "4f03-8938-94cav9857r2e",
    name: 'Orange Juice',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    price: 25.3
}
```

Comment: This question is kind of abstract - can you give some examples of your interface and infocations.

Comment: I edited my question to give you a more concrete example.